# How can I see what I've typed in irssi?

Tags: irssi

I've been using http://irssi.org for a while and it works great when I'm typing fewer than 80 or so characters on a line.

When I type more than 80 characters, however, the words I typed scroll off out of sight. In practice, this often isn't a problem if I've got a good stream of thought going. I just keep typing and hit enter at the end and all is well.

**The problem comes in when I'm halfway into a long line and I realize I need to go back and edit what I've typed.** I hit the left arrow and try to find the right place I want to edit. Then I right arrow back over and try to pick up the train of thought. With only about 80 characters visible at any one time, I sometimes make a mistake and introduce a grammatical error.

I'm open to a variety of solutions to this general problem. I haven't used irssi scripts before but I'm open to it.

Comment: Use the Home, End, Ctrl+←, Ctrl+→ alternatives to your advantage.

Comment: Recently, I've switched from irssi to Weechat (which is much more actively developed), and its input area automatically expands to multiple lines.

Answer (score 1):

irssi has many commands to move the cursor -
see eg http://www.guckes.net/irssi/#jumps
and there might be a script which allows
input to be spread across multiple lines.
please check http://scripts.irssi.org/

Answer (score 0):

Shoot, I had written a longish answer earlier today but it was lost, probably due to the maintenance that was performed.

In short, I got a tip from http://www.guckes.net/irssi/ and tried the following, which worked well:

```
vim ~/.irssi/inputline
/alias x /exec -out cat ~/.irssi/inputline
/x
```

The `/x` sends the input right into the window.

Another suggestion was to just make your window bigger, which will probably work for me in many case: http://irclog.perlgeek.de/crimsonfu/2013-02-09#i_6433568